# vscode won't start on arch linux

Tags: linux, arch-linux, visual-studio-code

Recently, my Visual Studio Code just stopped working. I downloaded it using `pacman -S code` (code-1.40.0-1), way before, and haven't touched it ever since. I looked for other places, but can't figure out what's wrong with it. I can run `electron4` all fine.

Whenever I try to run it:

```
$ code
electron4[41664]: ../../third_party/electron_node/src/node_file.cc:897:void node::fs::InternalModuleStat(const FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> &): Assertion `args[0]->IsString()' failed.
 1: 0x562f06bab8a6  [electron4]
 2: 0x562f06baa72c  [electron4]
 3: 0x562f06bf8cc7  [electron4]
 4: 0x562f034488a1  [electron4]
 5: 0x562f03caf24e  [electron4]
fish: 'code' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

Edit: vscodium-bin from AUR is working as intended

Answer (score 0):

Same Issue here.
Downgraded as workaround until the issue is fixed.
`sudo pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/code-1.39.2-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz`

Can't comment: Yeah thank you:
It is fixed:
`sudo pacman -S code`

now brings `Packages (2) electron6-6.1.1-1  code-1.40.0-2`

Comment: it worked! so the package is broken then

Answer (score 0):

It was a temporary bug [caused by Arch moving from Electron 6 to 7](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/64432?project=5&string=code), and VSCode not supporting 7 yet. A fix has been pushed to the repos, so just update and you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

This is already fixed at v1.40.0-2.
Thanks for maintainers!

```
$ pacman -Syu
```

https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/commit/trunk?h=packages/code&id=34ea20a2b94fed96b933f91b5cbd6094193af702